# What is the proper way to display a 3D model on top of a QGraphicsView?

Tags: opengl, qt4, qgraphicsview

I would like to display an image and a 3d model on top of that image. So far, I have used `QGraphicsView` to display a `QGraphicsScene` where I add the image as a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`.

The `QGraphicsView` is set up in:

```
ImageResourceWidget::ImageResourceWidget(ImageResource* resource, QWidget* parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
//QGraphicsScene m_scene;
//QGraphicsView m_view;
    m_view(&m_scene),
    m_pixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(resource->qimage())),
    m_zoom(1.0)
{
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    layout->addWidget(&m_view);
    setLayout(layout);

    QGLWidget* qgl=new QGLWidget(new QGLContext(QGLFormat(QGL::Rgba | QGL::DoubleBuffer | QGL::AlphaChannel | QGL::HasOverlay)));
    m_view.setViewport(qgl);

    _updateScene();

    connect(m_resource, SIGNAL(si_updateImage()), SLOT(updateImage()));
}
```

I try to draw on top of the `QGraphicsView` by overriding the `paintEvent` in the `ImageResourceWidget`:

```
void ImageResourceWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " -- paintEvent called." << std::endl;
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128, Qt::green);

//    from: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qpainter.html#beginNativePainting
//    painter.beginNativePainting();

//    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
//    glScissor(0, 0, 64, 64);

//    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
//    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
//    painter.endNativePainting();

      // For testing purposes:
      QPaintEngine::Type pType = m_view.paintEngine()->type(); // pType = QPaintEngine::X11, was expecting QPaintEngine::OpenGL(2)
      QPainter* p = m_view.paintEngine()->painter();           // p = 0x0, was expecting some other value
}
```

This will draw a green rectangle *behind* the `QGraphicsView`.

[This website](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html) suggests to subclass `QGraphicsScene`, however, I don't want the 3d model be a part of the scene. In other words, the 3d model should not be affected by transformations in the scene or view. It should just hover *on top* of the `QGraphicsView`.

I have also tried to subclass `QGraphicsView` (which seems to be the desired way, I think), but when I override the `paintEvent` in that class, nothing is displayed anymore and I get the warning: `QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent`

```
void MyGraphicsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) // inherits QGraphicsView
{
    this->QGraphicsView::paintEvent(event);
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " -- paintEvent called." << std::endl;

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128, Qt::green);

    // For testing purposes:
    QPaintEngine::Type pType = paintEngine()->type(); // pType = QPaintEngine::X11, was expecting QPaintEngine::OpenGL(2)
    QPainter* p = paintEngine()->painter();           // p = 0x0, was expecting some other value
}
```

**UPDATE**:

- I noticed that `paintEngine()->type()` returns `QPaintEngine::X11`, was expecting `QPaintEngine::OpenGL` after `m_view.setViewport(new QGlWidget(...))`.
- `paintEngine()->painter()` returns `0x0`, I was hoping to get access to the painter, so I could paint on the same surface.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to draw onto the viewport rather than on the QGraphicsView directly. I suppose the viewport is what contains the actual scene representation.
In any case I cannot figure out why you get the paint event error.